# Filtering JMESPath with a string

Tags: json, search, substring, contains, jmespath

I can't find the solution despite a lot of research. I'm stuck with the contains function.
I have this Json file:

```
    {
  "from": "Api",
  "success": true,
  "message": "",
  "errors": [],
  "data": {
    "operations": [
      {
        "IDOperation": 100,
        "DateEcriture": "2019-01-02",
        "Comment": "Invoice Nh5 numero 152",
        "sous_operations": []
      },
      {
        "IDOperation": 101,
        "DateEcriture": "2019-01-02",
        "Comment": "one other thing",
        "sous_operations": []
      },
      {
        "IDOperation":102,
        "DateEcriture": "2019-01-02",
        "Comment": "an other thing",
        "sous_operations": [{"ID-sous-Operation": 103,
                           "DateEcriture": "2019-01-02",
                           "Comment": "Invoice Nh15 numero 341"}]
      }]
   } 
}
```

And I want to filter the objects having the word "Invoice" in the "Comment" field to get this:

```
{"operations": [
      {
        "IDOperation": 100,
        "DateEcriture": "2019-01-02",
        "Comment": "Invoice Nh5 numero 152"
      },
      {
        "IDOperation": 103,
        "DateEcriture": "2019-01-02",
        "Comment": "Invoice Nh15 numero 341"
      }]
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't stated which part you're having difficulty with. I'm going to guess it's dealing with the nested sub-operations, since that seems the hardest and least obvious part to me, but I'll try to cover everything.

Here are my assumptions:

- Input always consists of an object with a field `data`.
- `data` field is always an object with a field `operations`.
- `operations` is always an array.
- Every member of `operations` has the same four fields: `IDOperation`, `DateEcriture`, `Comment`, `sous_operations`.
- `sous_operations` is always an array.
- Every member of `sous_operations` has the same three fields: `ID-sous-Operation` (!), `DateEcriture` and `Comment`.
- In particular, sub-operations are not nested more than one layer deep.
- All fields called `Comment` are strings.
- You want to find both the operations and sub-operations that have "Invoice" (case-insensitive) in their `Comment` field.
- You want to output them, but not any sub-operations they might have.
- You want to rename `ID-sous-Operation` to `IDOperation`.
- Output should consist of an object containing a single field `operations` which is an array of the selected and transformed operations.

I think this does what you want:

```
{
  operations:
    data.operations|
    map(
      &[
        [
          {
            IDOperation:IDOperation,
            DateEcriture:DateEcriture,
            Comment:Comment            
          }
        ],
        map(
          &{
            IDOperation:"ID-sous-Operation",
            DateEcriture:DateEcriture,
            Comment:Comment
          },
          sous_operations
        )
      ],
      @
    )|
    [][]|
    [?contains(Comment,`"Invoice"`)]
}
```

First, we replace every operation with a two-member array. The first member is a single element array containing the operation's fields but not its sub-operations. The second member is an array of all the operation's sub-operations. (At this point we also rename sub-operations ID field.)

So now we have operations as an array of (two element) arrays of arrays of simplified operations. We use the flatten operator twice to get a straightforward single-level array. Finally we filter it simply using the contains method.

Here's the output:

```
$ jp --filename input1.json --expr-file filter.jmespath
{
  "operations": [
    {
      "Comment": "Invoice Nh5 numero 152",
      "DateEcriture": "2019-01-02",
      "IDOperation": 100
    },
    {
      "Comment": "Invoice Nh15 numero 341",
      "DateEcriture": "2019-01-02",
      "IDOperation": 103
    }
  ]
}
```